# Drupal: losing images when moving site location; placeholders point to old absolute path rather than relative path

Tags: drupal, path

My file directories have not changed, but every time I move from local host to production, or just change the filename of a test site online, I loose the images.

Example: I've mainly been using an online location for building and testing Drupal sites, but recently I forgot to stop the robots from indexing a test site. So as a quick fix I just moved the site by changing the name of test test folder. When I first do this I loose images, but I also loose links from the admin menu because they point to the old absolute path too. (I don't seem to loose anything else like the theme, etc.) So I run update.php and flush the caches, and the admin menu links automatically point to the correct locations. But the image place holders still point to the old location instead of the new locations. It's very frustrating because I assume it's a simple fix but I just don't know how? Tks.

PS, first time using SO and I hope I'm posting this on the correct site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change $Base_URL in your settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks you thanks you.! A couple images still aren't working that I put into posts using the file-field insert, but I'll save that problem for another time!